# How to use filters in a different table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table for `Product`:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╗
║ ProjectID ║ ProductName ║ Manufacturer ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 1         ║ ABC         ║ A            ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 1         ║ XYZ         ║ B            ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 2         ║ LMN         ║ C            ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

When ever i have to fetch records according to it's manufacturer. i use below query.

```
select * from ProductMaster
where (Manufacturer like '%A%' or
       Manufacturer like '%B%' or
       Manufacturer like '%C%')
  and project_id=1
```

But now manufacturer has been increased (a-z).
and i want use it dynamically. I mean i don't want to use filters manually. i want to store these filters in other table and i can fetch these records with a procedure. can someone help me in doing it.

i have created a table for Manufacturer list(Filters).

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╗
║ ProjectID ║ Filters ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╣
║ 1         ║ A       ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╣
║ 1         ║ B       ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╣
║ 2         ║ A       ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╝
```

Note - Filters are diffrent for diffrent Projects.

Comment: What results do you want?  Your sample query returns all rows in the table.

Comment: @Larnu Still he doesn't provide the expected results.

Comment: Did you mean to @ someone else @Sami?

Comment: Aside: Why aren't you using `Manufacturer = 'X'` or `Manufacturer in ( 'X', 'Y', 'Z' )`? Is it because a product might have multiple manufacturers, e.g. `'N,F'`? Is it because a manufacturer might be more than a single letter, but you need to locate all products from manufacturers with vowels in their names? Or is it simply a desire to force a table (or index) scan rather than a seek? This looks like the kind of solution where you want to find all `'Ford'` products and you get back everything from `'Buford'` mixed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the filter-table in on the manufacturer-column and join it on `LIKE '%filter%'` using `CONCAT()`.

```sql
SELECT pm.* 
FROM ProductMaster AS pm
JOIN Filters AS f
    ON pm.ProjectID = f.ProjectID AND pm.Manufacturer LIKE CONCAT('%', f.Filters, '%')
WHERE pm.project_id=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is as simple as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ProductMaster
WHERE ProjectID = 1
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Filters
    WHERE Filters.ProjectID = ProductMaster.ProjectID
    AND ProductMaster.Manufacturer LIKE '%' + Filters.Filter '%'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will get you going.

The declared table accepts a series of proectids and some characters for the filter.
The query can then cross applied with this using a charindex to find a match on the relevant projectid with a manufacturer like the filter you are looking for.

```
declare @filters table

(
    ProjectID int, 
    Filters nvarchar(5)
);

insert @filters (ProjectID, Filters)
(1, 'A'),
(1, 'B'),
(1, 'C');

select p.* from ProductMaster p
cross apply (select f.projectid, filters from @filters f where where p.projectid=f.projectid and charindex(f.filters,p.Manufacturer,1)>0) x
```